# add data to a *.sdf file

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have create an application for windows, where i am using phone's sqlite as DB to store data. While testing the app in Emulator after the first time(i.e reinstallion of the app), the data of the DB gets erased every time.

So can any one please tell me How to:

1. Save the existing data of the DB before reinstalling the app.
2. Modify the .sdf file Manually (with out using the app)
3. To save the data in some other way, which will not be affected by the reinstallation of the app.

More Information regarding ways to add data to .sdf file are appreciated ...

Edit: Is it possible to browse and edit the .sdf file in phone when application gets installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the app via the Emulator, every time you close the emulator the app along with its components gets uninstalled. To prevent this , don't close the emulator everytime you run the app. Keep the emulator open, and run the program.

In the phone once the app is installed, the data is not deleted from the database and it is persisted.

The SDF can be modified using the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, add a database connection to SQL CE 3.5 and point to your sdf. You can modify the data from there.

You can also use the Isolated Storage explorer to open the SDF. http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Windows Phone Power Tools (http://wptools.codeplex.com) is also a good tool for grabbing files off the emulator before closing it.